# Configure log4j2 using tomcat context variables

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j2

I need to set some log4j configuration fields using tomcat context variables as source. Any idea?

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You need to edit your question to make it just a question and then provide a separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the jndi lookup (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#JNDILookup) in combination with property substituion (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution)
Here the extract of the tomcat context:

```
<Environment name="MongoDB.serverAddress.1.host" value="..." type="java.lang.String"/>
<Environment name="MongoDB.serverAddress.1.port" value="..." type="java.lang.String"/>
<Environment name="MongoDB.password" value="..." type="java.lang.String"/>
```

Here the extract of log4j2 configuration:

```
   <Configuration status="warn">
   <Properties>
    <Property name="MongoDbServer">$${jndi:MongoDB.serverAddress.1.host}:$${jndi:MongoDB.serverAddress.1.port}</Property>
    <Property name="MongoDbPassword">$${jndi:MongoDB.password}</Property>
</Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <NoSql name="databaseAppender">
            <MongoDb databaseName="SISTEMA" collectionName="applicationLog"
                server="${MongoDbServer}" username="SISTEMA"
                password="${MongoDbPassword}" />
        </NoSql>
    ....
```